# Simple adding split variables into object?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a simple answer but i am still learning so here i go. I have an object shade which you can see below. I also have a html value element which i am trying to split the value and place it into my object.

However its trying to add to shade.color.fill which doesnt exitst i need it to add to shade.color.cord instead.

```
value="type|Color"
```

Javascript

```
var obj = {
    color: {
        Type: null
    }
}

var fill = this.getAttribute('value').split("|");
shade.color.fill[0] = fill[1];
console.log(obj.type.color);
```

error:

```
TypeError: obj.type.fill is undefined
```

Comment: `fill[0] = cord` so your value will assign to `shade.color.cord` and you are accessing `shade.color.fill` which will give you `undefined` as error

Comment: @Apb You are Correct, however i am trying to add the fill[1] value into the object shade.color.cord and cord should be the value of fill[0]

Comment: Yes. So what is problem?

Comment: Try: `shade.color.fill = [fill[1]];`

Comment: @Apb the problem is that fill[0] value is a dynamic value so it can be "cord" or "trim" etc.. so i need it to write the fill[1] value to shade.color.cord instead. For example lets say i have trim|TT-399 Mood Indigo then it would write to shade.color.trim instead. does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do what I think you need to do, this should work (use square bracket notation as opposed to dot notation in order to set the name dynamically):

```
var shade = {
    color: {
        cord: null
    }
}

var fill = this.getAttribute('value').split("|");
shade.color[fill[0]] = fill[1];
console.log(shade.color.cord);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks what is the difference between the square to the dot notation?

Comment: @Elevant Square bracket notation accepts a string value as a key whereas dot notation accepts the name explicitly. Since you were setting the name from a string value you needed square brackets.